# PyQt5 Focus QMainWindow as first window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building an application in pyqt, which is called by another application with another graphical interface not built in pyqt. I have a QMainWindow, the problem is that when the boot appears behind the other application, and I do not know how to make it appear with the focus.
I try to pass window type in a constructor

```
Qt_WindowType
```

But does not work

This is my class

```
class Foo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        # more code...
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ScanGui(logger)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are exactly looking for I'd say to have a look in this flag:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

You can also make use of Modal modality.

[SetWindowModality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) instead of WindowStayOnTopHint, and both [modal modes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) (Qt.WindowModal and Qt.ApplicationModal) permit other applications to be on top of your modal window.

Comment: Thx. It works! I can use self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal) or self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) passing the parent to all the sub-windows I want to make appear later. Thank you!

Comment: YEHP!! cheers. If you need to understand better which one would be more appropriated to your problems just check the links I linked on. ")

Comment: This does not work if you want your modal to be  visible over fullscreen window.

Comment: Yes @Fusion, about that you may have to deal with its  "pid" through QProcess.pid() and call the underlying OS API to do it. A simpler way around would be ".close()" and ".open()" or ".show()" to make it comes to front. That's what I usually do, haha.